# Collect posts from last 48 hours

Tags: query-posts

I want to create a custom rss feed

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Feed
*/

function filter_where($where = '') {
    //posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
  }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'showposts' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
      );
$my_query=new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
?><rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>Something</title>
  <link>#</link>
  <description>The latest blog posts from #</description>
  <language>en-us</language>
<?
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
      <item>
    <title><?php the_title(); ?></title>
    <link><?php the_permalink() ?></link>
  </item>
     <?php
    endwhile;
  } //if ($my_query)?>
</channel>
</rss>
<?PHP wp_reset_query(); //just in case
?>
```

Now the final code for Custom Rss feed fetch from 48 hours. I can get right results from it.

Thanks for your help.

Mohammad Umer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never tested this ,but i believe you need to add WHERE clause to your query with time difference 
like so :

```
$timediff .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days')) . "'";
```

you can find it also in the codex

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters

If you do not want to use on query, but inside the loop, you could also do

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $mylimit=15 * 86400; //days * seconds per day
$post_age = date('U') - get_post_time('U');
if ($post_age < $mylimit) { ?>

// your functions or display here 

<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You give me right way but not complete function here is compete function